# Is there any way to generate test cases for constant files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5

When I try to generate test cases for constant file by using Diffblue cover. it shows "No methods found to test: Diffblue Cover was unable to find any methods that can be tested in your selection.". Is there any way to generate test cases for this file?

```java
public class ApiValidationErrorConstants {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL = "Account cannot be null";
    public static final String ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_NEGATIVE = "Account cannot be negative";
    public static final String APP_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL = "App cannot be null";
    public static final String INTEGRATION_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL = "Integration cannot be null";
    public static final String INTEGRATION_CANNOT_BE_NEGATIVE = "Integration cannot be negative";
}
```

Comment: When we write test cases we test the implementation of our application nothing but the methods in our application. If there is no implementation there is nothing to test. No test cases required for constants file.

Comment: If you were to manually write tests for this, what would they look like? Can you add a section to your question "I'd expect it to generate tests like ..."

Answer (score -1):

try adding a blank constructor

Comment: How it cover the constants?

Comment: you need at least one action to cover a class, thats why your test is not covering it